# Angularjs - Pagination appear after search filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am newbie on AngularJS.

**Search** result can be displayed in one page but **why** the **next and previous** button is **showing** ?

http://jsfiddle.net/2ZzZB/1473/

```
 <input type="text" id="txtNotessearch" ng-model="search_notes" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="SEARCH">
 ...
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in data | filter:search_notes | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
                    {{item}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: after my search only two result is appeared and then why pagination is coming.

Comment: I think s/he means that the search result can be displayed in one page but why the `next` and `previous` button is showing.

Comment: u don't need startFrom, `limitTo` [already have third option](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) `begin`, so, u can change ur code to `limitTo: pageSize: currentPage*pageSize`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because NumberOfPages is not filtered.
Instead of using $scope.data.length, you should use the length after the filter.

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $filter) { //Do not forget to inject $filter
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.pageSize = 10;
    $scope.data = [];

    $scope.numberOfPages=function(){
        var myFilteredData = $filter('filter')($scope.data,$scope.search_notes); //Filter the data
        return Math.ceil(myFilteredData.length/$scope.pageSize);                
    }
    for (var i=0; i<45; i++) {
        $scope.data.push("Item "+i);
    }
}
```

In addition, I would modify the ng-disable next button to

```
button "ng-disabled="(currentPage + 1) == numberOfPages()"
```

And I would add to search_notes onchange currentPage=1.

Here you have the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/rLots5zd/

Comment: Could you please provide me the jsfiddle link for example?

Comment: Hi Madhes, I've updated the answer with the code and the fiddle

Comment: I have some query,If I'm in 3rd page and i will search "15".Now next and previous button is problem

Comment: Yes Madhes, that's because I suggested to change to currentPage = 1 when you change your Search input :)

Answer (score 0):

In case, you want to hide the `next` and `previous` button when the result can be displayed in one page, please see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rLots5zd/3/