# how implement pagination and searching on json in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, pagination

how implement pagination and searching on json in angularjs.
I have seen multiple example on list to implement pagination like below

[How to do paging in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816073/how-to-do-paging-in-angularjs)

[Angularjs - Pagination appear after search filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524713/angularjs-pagination-appear-after-search-filter)

But i need to do on js object not on json array(or list). 
May be simlar to 
[Pagination on JSON Data in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899065/pagination-on-json-data-in-angular)

sample data

```
  {"a":"hsdhs","b":"hsdhs","c":"hsdhs","d":"hsdhs","e":"hsdhs","f":"hsdhs","g":"hsdhs"}
```

if iam there in page no 2 and page size is 3. then i need only

```
     {"d":"hsdhs","e":"hsdhs","f":"hsdhs"}
```

Can some one help me findout this.

Thank you

Comment: Convert the Object to an Array with a custom Angular Filter could be an option. Then the pagination will be easier to handle.

Comment: Basically i am reciving array for some other process i need to get converted to object. I cant convert back and show on ui. No other method for object pagination ?

Comment: Could you provide a plnkr so I can help you.